# Running out of storage space - want to move Mist chaindata

Tags: mist, storage, datadir

I have a small laptop that I basically use for nothing but my Ethereum wallet, using Mist. I'm running out of space, so I added a 64gb SD card and I'd like to keep Mist running on the laptop but store the blockchain data to the SD card.

I [followed instructions](/questions/1724/possible-to-store-the-blockchain-in-a-different-directory) for making that change in Geth via terminal - designating `--datadir` to the directory of the SD card - but it doesn't seem to make any difference when I open Mist. The entries in the chaindata folder on my laptop's storage keep expanding and nothing appears on the SD card. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/ethereum/mist#using-mist-with-a-privatenet)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: It's not clear what OS you're using.  If Windows, try this: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/my-c-drive-in-my-windows-pc-is-almost-full-how-can-i-change-both-geth-and-mist/3830#3830

Answer (score 2):

Mist has the data directory hard coded.

If you want to run geth directly, you can use `--datadir`. You might also use a symbolic link.

Not much more to say on this other than submit an issue on the Mist project if you'd like to see this changed.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Well that settles that then. Thanks for the response! I've still got about 5gb of headroom, so hopefully a change is implemented before I run out, or worst case scenario I'll have to set up a wallet on another computer. In the meantime, I will submit a pull request as you suggest.

Comment: @Ethcurious had a brain fart, pull/issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not tried this myself but how about creating a Symbolic Link to the chain data directory. e.g. something like

```
ln -s /sdcard/chaindata usr/library/ethereum/chaindata
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can run mist with `--node-datadir="path/to/datadir"` option to specify your data directory