# Downloading Mist Chaindata to a New Storage Device

Tags: mist, storage

The computer I am working on has an SSD and HDD. The Chaindata was originally set to download to the SSD, but the SSD has run out of storage. The computer is running Mist; how can I either

(1) move the entire Mist directory to the HDD or

(2) direct the Chaindata to specifically download to the HDD?

Comment: Have a look over here. Helpful? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2551/how-to-set-a-different-datadir-in-mist

Comment: If you're running windows, check here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/my-c-drive-in-my-windows-pc-is-almost-full-how-can-i-change-both-geth-and-mist/3830#3830