# Can't open ethereum wallet when blockchain is on my SSD

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, datadir

After a lot of searching I found how to set the datadir path to download the blockchain on my SSD instead of my :C/ drive since that's almost full

and now that it's downloading the blockchain i would normally be able to open the wallet without issue but It's giving me an error saying "Ethereum node cannot run. Is another instance running?"

I assume it's because on starting the ethereum wallet exe file from my computer while the blockchain data is on my SSD, but when i tried starting the exe file from my SSD is says "the progrom can't start because node.dll is missing from your computer"

anyone have an idea of what i should do?

Comment: What is your geth command line?

Comment: the command line i use is --datadir G:/Ethereum --cache 1024

Comment: From Ethereum Wallet it is launched with `--fast --cache 1024 --ipcpath \\.\pipe\geth.ipc`, try with the extra parameters. Another option is to pass the parameters to "Ethereum Wallet": _To pass options to the underlying node (e.g. Geth) use the --node- prefix,  e.g. --node-datadir._

Comment: See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/21646

Comment: Im sorry im dumb I don't really understand

so I would launch Ethereum Wallet through cmd with "--datadir <location> --fast --cache 1024 --ipcpath \\.\pipe\geth.ipc"

with the ipc path part am I locating that particular file? or am I setting the location for that file to go?

Comment: You should launch `geth --datadir <location> --fast --cache 1024 --ipcpath \\.\pipe\geth.ipc`.

Comment: I tried putting that in, but the same issue occurs. I'm not able to open the Ethereum Wallet

Comment: Sorry, but I've just checked it works in Windows 10. `geth --datadir <mypath> --fast --cache 1024 --ipcpath \\.\pipe\geth.ipc`, wait a little to start synchronization and then launch "Ethereum Wallet.exe" and it should connect to running geth. Started both from cmd.exe windows.